# MPMoviePlayerController failed with itemFailedToPlayToEnd

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, movie, video-player

I have retrieved movies file from my iPhone Photo Library, and saved them into my App`s Documents directory. When I click one movie file, I want to use MPMoviePlayerController to play it. Unfortunately, It fail to play the movie file with such error:

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
  }
```

I have searched for a long time to resolve this problem. Somebody say the format maybe is unsupport. The movies file is retrieved from Photo Library, so the format should be OK. Also, I copy the file to NSBundle and MPMoviePlayerController can play it. So the file is OK. Following is my codes:

```
    NSString *newstr = [mFilePath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    DLog(@"the raw is %@ the newstr is %@", mFilePath, newstr);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:newstr];
    DLog(@"the url is %@", url);
#if 0
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    if (bundle) {
        NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"MOV"];
        if (path) {
            url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
            DLog(@"the new url is %@", url);
        }
    }
#endif

    mPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [mPlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];
    [mPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [mPlayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];

    [mPlayer play];
    [self.view addSubview:mPlayer.view];
```

Comment: getting the same error, but not when I play directly from the server...

Answer (score 0):

Changing:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
```

to

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```

fixed it for me, then:

```
mPlayer.contentURL = url;
[mPlayer prepareToPlay];
```

but you already do this correctly. I create the mPlayer once and then just shift the contentURL about (instead of alloc + initWithContentURL) for different videos. Have you tried that?